# Передать переменную в callback функцию javascript

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста с такой проблемой, с js вообще не разбираюсь, есть код:

```
result = $.parseJSON(response);
            output = result.data;

            google.charts.load('current', {
                callback: function() {
                    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
                        cols: [{
                                label: 'time',
                                type: 'string'
                            },
                            {
                                label: 'x1',
                                type: 'number'
                            },
                            {
                                label: 'x2',
                                type: 'number'
                            },
                            {
                                label: 'x3',
                                type: 'number'
                            }
                        ],
                        rows: [
                            output
                        ]
                    });

                    var container = document.getElementById('chart');
                    var options = {
                        displayAnnotations: true
                    }
                    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(container);
                    chart.draw(data, {
                        height: 600,
                        series: {
                            1: {
                                targetAxisIndex: 1,
                            },
                            2: {
                                targetAxisIndex: 1,
                            }
                        },
                        theme: 'material',
                        vAxes: {
                            0: {
                                title: 'x1'
                            },
                            1: {
                                title: 'x2, x3'
                            }
                        }
                    });
                },
                packages: ['corechart']
            });
```

Мне нужно подставить значение output в

```
rows: [
output
]
```

вместо output. Как мне сделать такое?

Comment: при даном коде что за ошибка в консоли?

Comment: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.Wf[a].c[b]')×

Comment: значит контекст надо передавать, к примеру функцией bind()

Comment: Можно пример как будет в моем случае?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/bind